# How to append an existing XML file using DOM without overwriting the existing data? in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, append

i have a very confused about the how the xml data can be append to already existed data give me your suggestions my code is like this

```
 Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();//db.newDocument();//create document

        Element root = doc.createElement("Employees");//cretae Elements
        doc.appendChild(root);

        Comment cmt = doc.createComment("Employee Details");//Add comment to xml
        root.appendChild(cmt);

        Element employee = doc.createElement("employee");//create Element
        //employee.appendChild(doc.)
        root.appendChild(employee);

        Attr genderAttr = doc.createAttribute("Gender");
        System.out.print("Enter your gender :");
        String gend = br.readLine();
        genderAttr.setValue(gend);
        employee.setAttributeNode(genderAttr);

        System.out.print("Enter first name:");
        String child = br.readLine();
        Element FName = doc.createElement("firstName");
        FName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(child));//set xml text
        employee.appendChild(FName);

        System.out.print("Enter last name:");
        String child1 = br.readLine();
        Element LName = doc.createElement("lastName");            
        LName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(child1));
        employee.appendChild(LName);

        //root.appendChild(employee);
        //doc.appendChild(root);

        //to write on file/screen
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);//source             
        //File shopOrder = new File("src"+File.separator+"xmlparsing"+File.separator+"xmlParse1.xml");//get the file
        StreamResult res = new StreamResult(new File("src"+File.separator+"xmlparsing"+File.separator+"xmlParse1.xml"));//Destination
        tr.transform(source, res);//to write on file
```

and i can do easily parse and update also but i can't understand how i can append previous data please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Say, you want to append new `Employees` to your XML. Instead of creating a new root you'd simply find it using `getElementsByName()` like

```
// find root
NodeList rootList = doc.getElementsByName("Employees");
Node root = rootList.item(0);

Element employee = doc.createElement("employee"); //create new Element
root.appendChild(employee); // append as before
```

There's a `Document.getElementById()` method as well that you could use if an element has been assigned an identifier. To insert something deep down the tree use `XPath` to find the node first then `append()` as usual.

***EDIT :** (Sample code added)*
You can't have two root nodes i.e. two `<Employees>` tags as root. That's invalid XML. What you need is multiple `<Employee>` tags inside one single root `<Employees>` tag. Also, stick to either camel or capital case. I'm using capitals for consistency.

```
// find root
NodeList rootList = doc.getElementsByName("Employees");
Node root = rootList.item(0);

// append using a helper method
root.appendChild(createEmployee(doc, "male", "John", "Doe"));

public Element createEmployee(Document doc,
                              String gender, String fname, String lname) {
  // create new Employee
  Element employee = doc.createElement("Employee");
  employee.setAttribute("gender", gender);

  // create child nodes
  Element firstName = doc.createElement("FirstName");
  firstName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(fname));

  Element lastName = doc.createElement("LastName");
  lastName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lname));

  // append and return
  employee.appendChild(firstName);
  employee.appendChild(lastName);

  return employee;
}
```

Comment: @Durgaprasad: post code, XML or any other structured text as an edit to your question, not in a comment. It's impossible to read when it's unformatted this way.

Comment: You can't have two root nodes i.e. two `<Employees>` tags. That's invalid XML. Check the sample code I've added. Should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for giving valuable info actually that comment is mistakenly typed